# How do I stop event propagation in d3 using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typescript, typescript-typings

In JavaScript, I have code like the following to stop event propagation when something is being dragged.

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .on('dragstart', function(e) {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  })
  .on('drag', function(e) { ... });
```

In TypeScript, I noticed that `d3.event.sourceEvent` doesn't exists. Below is the corresponding TypeScript code.

```
let drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin( (d, i) => {
    let data = d as any;
    return { x: data.x as number, y: data.y as number };
  })
  .on('dragstart',  (d, i) => { 
    //what to do here
   })
  .on('drag', (d, i) => { ... });
```

In fact, the `on` method signature has changed in TypeScript. The declaration file looks like the following.

```
export module behavior {
 interface Drag<Datum> {
  on(type: string): (d: Datum, i: number) => any;
  on(type: string, listener: (d: Datum, i: number) => any): Drag<Datum>;
 }
}
```

Below are my npm dependencies related to d3.

- "@types/d3": "3.5.37"
- "d3": "^3.5.16"

Any idea on how to do the same thing in TypeScript?

Comment: I think it's supposed to be `d3.event.stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I had to do some casting.

```
let event = d3.event as d3.BaseEvent;
event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: I had the same problem using Scala.js and your answer helped me find the solution: d3.event.asInstanceOf[MouseEvent].stopPropagation()